# What is the MySQL Mutex called "srv_sys_mutex"?

Tags: mysql, performance

For the purposes of diagnosing performance issues, what kinds of operations might wait their turn for this mutex, and what configuration options and resources might influence contention on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a system mutex. It's used to protect creating new threads, destroying them.
I guess, [thread_cache_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size) may ease contention on it.